# How to define the new vector in my case?

Tags: math, vector, linear-algebra, vector-graphics

This is probably more like a mathematics question:

If I have a vector:

```
var origin = new Vector(x, y)
```

then, I would like to get **N** sub vectors, each one of the **N** sub vector is got by adding `origin` vector with a new vector, like:

```
subVector = origin.add(new Vector(m, n));
```

The result I would like to achieve is showing in the image below:
[image]

I would like to get **N** sub vectors which are in the **same horizontal leve** and **spaced by "L" length**,

**My questions are:**

**1.** what is the new vector (`Vector(m, n)`) **m**, **n** values I should
    use to get all the sub vectors ? (**N** is dynamic value)

```
I end up with something like:

    for(var i=0; i<N; i++){

        //But, how to select the m, n value here??
        var subVector = origin.add(new Vector(m, n)); 
    }
```

**2.** How to choose the new vector (`Vector(m, n)`) **m**, **n** value to make sure the **distance** between two neighboring sub vectors is **L** as showed in the image ?

Comment: You're right - this is a math question expressed here using Vector. I'm no mathematician but it's probably in the realms of set theory or something similar. Why not ask it on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) to figure out the algorithm for what you're trying to do, and then come back if you have trouble encoding that algorithm in your software?

Comment: yes this is a math question - but I don't really understand your need. For example - can you ellaborate "horizontal" in respect to your "origin"-vector? Because for thinks like "horizontal"/"vertical" you need a base but you only given the origin for such a base "or so I guess". Your picture sugguest that "horizontal" is just "same y-values" and you the cartesian coordinate-base. but then the answer is straightforward - given subvectors s1,s2 just add multiples of (s2-s1) to s2 to get the others - you don't need the origina at all

Answer (score 2):

Because the first of the subvectors can be anything (say v = (v1,v2)), then you need to add to the first subvector to get the others. At each iteration you add the vector (L, 0):

`var secondSubvector = firstSubvector.add(new Vector(L, 0))`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you like to have more a point than a vector? I cannot see what you will achieve with it. And if you like to have the same horizontal level you just have have to change the x-axis parameter but not the y in 2D-Space.
I guess (!) it's the lenght you have to add to your X-axis parameter:

subVector = new Vector(origing.X + Length, origing.Y)

Let me know if I get you wrong or it helped.

Stef